# Mirror browser window to second window

Tags: google-chrome, display, external-display, chromecast

I have two displays set-up, one facing me, one facing a customer.

I want to mirror the content of a page shown in Chrome to the second screen, without any of the other applications being displayed on the second screen.

That means:

- Primary screen: Display all behaviour as regular, including Chrome
- Secondary screen: Display only Chrome

Is there a possibility to do that?